# product collection sorting by price is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, category, price, sorting, sort

I want to sort the product collection by price. For this i am using

`->setOrder('price', 'DESC') or ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'DESC')` is not working but it is working with `->addAttributeToSort('name','DESC')` perfectly.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds));
```

Comment: what u r  problem ->setOrder('price', 'DESC') no working or addAttributeToSort()  not working

Comment: Both are not working with price.

Answer (score 5):

Try this add price to collection:

```
$_productCollection->joinAttribute(
            'price',
            'catalog_product/price',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'left',
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
        );
```

Or

```
$_productCollection
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
```

### Some Additional  info:

**setOrder()** does not works `because of`

> Magent use Eav  Structure for product attributes
>   Whenever magento add an attribute to it product Collection then it join  the collection with product attribute respective table (example catalog_product_varchar,catalog_product_ etc.)
>
> And  give an alias name to that  attribute table  and this attribute name in collection.

As you have using **setOrder('price', 'DESC')** that it **trying field to main table**  `catalog_product_entity` which does not exit that why it is not works.

But whenever you use `addAttributeToSort()` function magento build  automatically logic which  properly call the field

```
  if (isset($this->_staticFields[$attribute])) {
            $this->getSelect()->order("e.{$attribute} {$dir}");
            return $this;
        }
        if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$attribute])) {
            $attrInstance = $this->_joinAttributes[$attribute]['attribute'];
            $entityField = $this->_getAttributeTableAlias($attribute) . '.' . $attrInstance->getAttributeCode();
        } else {
            $attrInstance = $this->getEntity()->getAttribute($attribute);
            $entityField = 'e.' . $attribute;
        }

        if ($attrInstance) {
            if ($attrInstance->getBackend()->isStatic()) {
                $orderExpr = $entityField;
            } else {
                $this->_addAttributeJoin($attribute, 'left');
                if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$attribute])||isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {
                    $orderExpr = $attribute;
                } else {
                    $orderExpr = $this->_getAttributeTableAlias($attribute).'.value';
                }
            }
```

You can the fundamental logic  of `addAttributeToSort()` on class  [`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php)

**That reason magento use  AddAttributeToSort() to filter the product collection**

Comment: It's also not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue

```
$categoryIds = array($_category_id); //category id
                            $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
                            $category->load($_category_id); // this is category id
                            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id)
                                                ->getProductCollection()
                                                ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId())
                                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
                                                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
                                                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
                                                ->setOrder('price', 'ASC'); //sets the order by price
```

Answer (score 0):

use set `setOrder`

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds));
```

Comment: I had also tried ->setOrder('price', 'ASC'), it is also not working with price.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way for it is `$this->_collection->getSelect()->order('min_price desc');`